# How to track a secondary index id

Tags: php, mysql

Have a table that will be shared by multiple users. The basic table structure will be:

```
unique_id | user_id  | users_index_id | data_1 | data_2 etc etc
```

With the id fields being type int and unique_id being an primary key with auto increment.

The data will be something like:

```
unique_id | user_id | users_index_id
1 | 234 | 1
2 | 234 | 2
3 | 234 | 3
4 | 234 | 4
5 | 732 | 1
6 | 732 | 2
7 | 234 | 5
8 | 732 | 3
```

How do I keep track of 'users_index_id' so that it 'auto increments' specifically for a user_id ?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. As I've searched for an answer but am not sure I'm using the correct terminology to find what I need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way to do this consistently is by using a "before insert" and "before update" trigger.  MySQL does not directly support this syntax.  You could wrap all changes to the table in a stored procedure and put the logic there, or use very careful logic when doing an `insert`:

```
insert into table(user_id, users_index_id)
    select user_id, count(*) + 1
    from table
    where user_id = param_user_id;
```

However, this won't keep things in order if you do `delete` or some updates.

You might find it more convenient to calculate the `users_index_id` when you query rather than in the database.  You can do this using either subqueries (which are probably ok with the right indexes on the table) or using variables (which might be faster but can't be put into a view).

If you have an index on `table(user_id, unique_id)`, then the following query should work pretty well:

```
select t.*,
       (select count(*) from table t2 where t2.user_id = t.user_id and t2.unique_id <= t.unique_id
       ) as users_index_id
from table t;
```

You will need the index for non-abyssmal performance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to find the `MAX(users_index_id)` and increment it by one. To avoid having to manually lock the table to ensure a unique key you will want to perform the `SELECT` within your `INSERT` statement. <strike>However, MySQL does not allow you to reference the target table when performing an `INSERT` or `UPDATE` statement unless it's wrapped in a subquery:</strike>

```
INSERT INTO users (user_id, users_index_id) VALUES (234, (SELECT IFNULL(id, 0) + 1 FROM (SELECT MAX(users_index_id) id FROM users WHERE user_id = 234) dt))
```

Query without subselect (thanks Gordon Linoff):

```
INSERT INTO users (user_id, users_index_id) SELECT 234, IFNULL((SELECT MAX(users_index_id) id FROM users WHERE user_id = 234), 0) + 1;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/eaea9a/1/0

Comment: "MySQL does not allow you to reference the target table when performing an `INSERT` or `UPDATE` statement unless it's wrapped in a subquery".  This statement is simply false.  MySQL fully supports the `insert . . . select` syntax, which is ANSI standard and supported by all databases (that I know of).  The `select` part can refer to the table with inserts.  MySQL also supports using the same table in updates using the `join` syntax.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I may have phrased my intention incorrectly, maybe you can help me clear it up? Please test the following statement against the provided sqlfiddle schema: `INSERT INTO users (user_id, users_index_id) VALUES (234, IFNULL((SELECT MAX(users_index_id) id FROM users WHERE user_id = 234), 0) + 1);` - you should receive the error `SQL Error (1093): You can't specify target table 'users' for update in FROM clause`.

Comment: . . I would never personally use a nested `select` in a `values` statement, because the `insert . . . select` works just fine.  You made a blanket statement about what can and cannot be done.  The blanket statement is not true.  There are syntactic constructs that produce errors, as you have pointed out.

Comment: @GordonLinoff you're correct, I'm not sure what I was thinking initially. I've updated my answer accordingly. Thanks for your feedback.